# Session/Cookies Expiration inquiry

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

I have an .net/.aspx web application with basic authentication (through web service from third party).

**The program flow is as follows:**
 - User logs in on the login page (Username and Password)
 - .aspx.cs (CodeBehind) handles the web service authentication.
 - If the user is authenticated, I will set the following: HttpContent.Current.Session["IsLogged"]=1;

I also configured my web.config for my session timeouts by using the following lines:

```
 < sessionState timeout="10" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
 < httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
```

Based from my understanding, if no action occurred while I am logged in within 10 minutes, the session will expire.

What I did so far was to log in on the web application then close it immediately, and I didn't accessed the web application for 20 minutes.  Now when I opened the web application, I am still logged in.  Am I doing something wrong?

My real objective is, when I closed the web application (or got idled) for more than 10 minutes, my session cookies will expired.  How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you actively reload the page, to make sure you didn't just see a cached version?

Comment: Hi Alexander, I haven't tried that.  I will get back to you after 10-20 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the timeout in Application Pool?

Check below screenshot and also refer this [link](http://asp-net.vexedlogic.com/2012/05/23/aspasp-net-session-timeout-how-do-i-change-it/)

[image]